# Best way to decompose addition of waveforms?

Tags: filter, signal, rms

I am searching for a way to decompose the exact components of additions of known waveforms.

For example, lets say there is a waveform that is sum of multiple sinc functions.
The sinc function's overall shape (or the period) is known. However, the amplitude and the center of the sinc functions are unknown.

If the question is too difficult, we can also assume we know the quantity of the sinc function components.

In this scenario, what will be the most efficient (or smart) way to decompose the signal?

I have tried matched filtering, but this seems to fail in finding the exact components.
Currently, my best answer is to find the best match by subtracting the waveform with all possible combinations.
However, this process is rather clumsy and very slow.

Any search keywords or very simple directions will be greatly appreciated.

It is my first time using this community. Please kindly tell me if there are any problems with my question, and I will fix it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: google FFT (fast fourier transform)

Comment: Fourier series provide the decomposition to the sine waves, if these are the "waveforms" you are talking about. If the "waveforms" are more complex, then you need Fourier decomposition of each one of these, and then see whose components present in the original signal.

Comment: Using a multichannel "correlation" technique would be effective if you know the "overall shape" of what you are searching?

Comment: Something as this? ... but for real signals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation

Comment: I found also this (in french) https://www.electronique-mixte.fr/arduino-sinus-cardinal/#